# Recover port from Boost Asio udp::endpoint

Tags: networking, boost, udp, boost-asio, endianness

I am programming a server and client program to communicate between a windows PC using the Boost libraries and a Linux ARM beagleboard using the asio stand alone libraries. I have for a while had successful UDP communication between the two devices but now I want to recover the port from the endpoint the server discovers when the client connects. The way the client connects is via query:

```
udp::resolver resolver(io_service);
udp::resolver::query query_tx(udp::v4(), hostIP, "43210");
udp::endpoint receiver_endpoint_tx = *resolver.resolve(query_tx);
```

where host IP is a string and this works fine. Upon debugging though I notice that when i check the value returned by:

```
receiver_endpoint_tx.port()
```

This returns 51880. Now don't jump the guns and yell out network byte order and host byte order. I AM AWARE. The strange part is that this number 51880 sometimes is a different number and when i check what the server has stored in its endpoint it is a completely different number: 21743. Now I know I must be doing something wrong with the byte orders but i tried:

```
//unsigned long port_long       = boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::host_to_network_long(receiver_endpoint_tx.port());
//unsigned long port_short      = boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::host_to_network_short(receiver_endpoint_tx.port());
```

And they do not give me back my original port: 43210. Neither does network to host. So what am i missing and how can I on both ends recover my 43210 port? Obviously it must be there somewhere because they are successfully communicating.
Thanks in advance, sorry if noob mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

Fistly, UDP is connectionless, there is no *connection*.

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but it sound too me like you want to bind to specific port numbers. If you want the client to send a packet from port x to port y on the server, and the server should respond from port y to port x, then you need to [bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/bind.html) the sockets to the desired ports. Alternatively you can use the [constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/basic_datagram_socket/overload3.html) to bind. Not doing so will result in the OS using [ephemeral ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

Further, to get the remote endpoint that a packet was received from the `async_receive_from` takes the `sender_endpoint` reference parameter. When the read handler is called, you can retrieve host and port from it.

Comment: Thanks Ralf! That answered my question. I thought that when I specified a port to have a chat on, both sides used the same port and were automatically bound to it!